# Gradle shouldRunAfter not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to run my custom task after assembleDebug task in Android Studio.My normal build.gradle is

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
   ...
 }

 dependencies {
   ...
 }

 task printName{
    println 'Hello Guffy'
 }

 printName.shouldRunAfter(tasks.assembleDebug)
 // or printName.shouldRunAfter(assembleDebug)
 // or assembleDebug.shouldRunAfter(printName)
```

which is not compiling.The gradle error is

```
Error:(36, 0) Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for task set
```

Is assembleDebug or other tasks not available to custom tasks ? Or is there any basic error I am doing ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe try 
 printName.shouldRunAfter("assembleDebug") Also are you using flavors?

Comment: Thanks , that worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested by  Piotr Zawadzki, putting task in quotes worked .

So the code should be like

```
  printName.shouldRunAfter("assembleDebug")
```